# Using dart discoveryapis_generator on webapp?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-endpoints

Can't use my model file generated with the [discoveryapis_generator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/discovery_api_client_generator).

It ask for a http.client to be used, but it's from [dart:io](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io), and i m trying to use it in a web app

```
static YoupipeApi api = new YoupipeApi(new http.Client()); //cant work on webapp
```

> Failed to invoke tokenLoaded callback: Unsupported operation: IOClient isn't supported on this platform.

So, discoveryapis_generator is only available for native dart client? 
Am i doing something wrong?

([related question here](https://github.com/dart-lang/discoveryapis_generator/issues/149))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http package also contains a client that runs in the browser. Just change the import to import the file `package:http/browser_client.dart;` instead.